# What problems do configuration management tools solve?

Tags: configuration-management

My company is creating a service in an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud. Without getting too much into the details, there will be about 5 different types of servers, and each type will need to be replicated based on demand. A bit of reading gives me the impression that we're going to want to use a config management tool like Puppet or Chef.

My bosses are receptive to the idea, but need convincing that it's actually worth the upfront cost of learning one of these tools. I have no experience with these tools, and can't really offer anything other than a few bullet points on what they do, and that wiser people on the internet seem to think it's a good idea.

The benefits of a CM just seem like vague best practices at this point, since I haven't yet experienced the problems that they are meant to solve. What headaches can I expect if we don't use a config management tool?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I also found [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995290/why-do-people-use-puppet-chef-with-amazon-cloud-formation-instead-of-just-using) very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start point look at this info - [Configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management). The concept itself is very broad, that you may need to narrow it down on certain areas.

> CM, when applied over the life cycle of a system, provides visibility
>   and control of its performance, functional and physical attributes. CM
>   verifies that a system performs as intended, and is identified and
>   documented in sufficient detail to support its projected life cycle.
>   The CM process facilitates orderly management of system information
>   and system changes for such beneficial purposes as to revise
>   capability; improve performance, reliability, or maintainability;
>   extend life; reduce cost; reduce risk and liability; or correct
>   defects. The relatively minimal cost of implementing CM is returned
>   many fold in cost avoidance.

In addition to Wikipedia, look at this summarized article to get more in-depth thoughts - [Configuration Management Tools Summary](http://www.daveeaton.com/scm/CMTools.html).